# Unable to add Navigation dependency to the build.gradle file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, navigation, build.gradle

Here is my build.gradle app or module file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.miwok"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])   
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'  
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    def nav_version = "2.2.1"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // Dynamic Feature Module Support
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"
}
```

I also added the `android.useAndroidX=true` line to the properties file.
Getting these Errors:
ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.2.1
ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:2.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `navigation-testing` and `navigation-dynamic-features-fragment` artifacts were only introduced in [Navigation `2.3.0-alpha01`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.3.0-alpha01) with the current version being `2.3.0-alpha04`. You'll want to update your `nav_version` to at least that version if you want to use those artifacts.

Comment: I am also getting android resource linking failed after building the project. Heard many of your talks, new android developer here. You're amazing!

Comment: There's a lot of really, really out of date things in your Gradle file (you haven't moved to AndroidX, you compile with SDK 23, etc.). You should probably update all of those things first and [Migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) before you do anything else.

Comment: Great! Best of luck going forward :)

Comment: Here is a PR implementing navigation between dynamic feature modules https://github.com/igorwojda/android-showcase/pull/98/files (`2.3.0-alpha06`)